# Why does xmlbeans-maven-plugin seem to ask for jdk 1.4 went higher jdk is provided?

Tags: java, xml, maven, xmlbeans, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I'm migrating a old lib to java 8 (and after 11 and 17) and I'm getting a error saying I'm of java 1.4 on our build server (local build is working fine):

```
17:53:21  [INFO] --- xmlbeans-maven-plugin:2.3.3:xmlbeans (default) @ edoc-deeplink-intact-xml ---
17:53:29  warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
17:53:29  error: Source option 1.4 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
17:53:29  error: Target option 1.4 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
```

However my effective pom seem to be on java 1.8 so I don't understand why I'm getting this error.
Here the effective pom:

```
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project                                              -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>parent-poms</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>common</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-xml-lib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jdependMavenPluginVersion>2.0-beta-2</jdependMavenPluginVersion>
    <jdk>1.8</jdk>
    <jdk.arch>64</jdk.arch>
    <jdk.vendor>redhat</jdk.vendor>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <mavenAntrunPluginVersion>1.7</mavenAntrunPluginVersion>
    <mavenCheckstylePluginVersion>2.10</mavenCheckstylePluginVersion>
    <mavenDeployPluginVersion>2.7</mavenDeployPluginVersion>
    <mavenEnforcerPluginVersion>1.2</mavenEnforcerPluginVersion>
    <mavenJavadocPluginVersion>2.9</mavenJavadocPluginVersion>
    <mavenJxrPluginVersion>2.3</mavenJxrPluginVersion>
    <mavenPluginPluginVersion>3.2</mavenPluginPluginVersion>
    <mavenPmdPluginVersion>3.0.1</mavenPmdPluginVersion>
    <mavenProjectInfoReportsPluginVersion>2.6</mavenProjectInfoReportsPluginVersion>
    <mavenSourcePluginVersion>2.2.1</mavenSourcePluginVersion>
    <mavenSurefirePluginVersion>2.15</mavenSurefirePluginVersion>
    <mavenSurefireReportPluginVersion>2.14.1</mavenSurefireReportPluginVersion>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <taglistMavenPluginVersion>2.4</taglistMavenPluginVersion>
    <timestamp>2023-05-29T21:46:36Z</timestamp>
    <versionsMavenPluginVersion>2.1</versionsMavenPluginVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>C:\Data\my-xml-lib\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.15</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.10</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <pushChanges>true</pushChanges>
            <useEditMode>false</useEditMode>
            <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.10</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
          <configuration>
            <version>6</version>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.3.3,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                      <goal>xmlbeans-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <inherited>true</inherited>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-javadocs</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <quiet>true</quiet>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <quiet>true</quiet>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
          <configuration>
            <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.google.code.echo-maven-plugin</groupId>
          <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>descriptor</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>help-goal</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>helpmojo</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>regex-property</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>regex-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <name>shortGroupId</name>
              <value>common</value>
              <regex>^TOKEN\.(.+)</regex>
              <replacement>$1</replacement>
              <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <quiet>true</quiet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <quiet>true</quiet>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration combine.self="override">
          <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
          <workingDirectory>F:/Data/rel/${buildDefinitionId}/${buildLabel}</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
              <includes>
                <include>about.html</include>
              </includes>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jenkins-plugin</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>toolchain</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <toolchains>
                <jdk>
                  <version>1.8</version>
                  <vendor>redhat</vendor>
                  <arch>64</arch>
                </jdk>
              </toolchains>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <toolchains>
            <jdk>
              <version>1.8</version>
              <vendor>redhat</vendor>
              <arch>64</arch>
            </jdk>
          </toolchains>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
              <goal>xmlbeans-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <schemaDirectory>//Path-to-schemaDirectory</schemaDirectory>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <schemaDirectory>//Path-to-schemaDirectory</schemaDirectory>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: it's been a while that I've migrated the plugin and I'm not active anymore, but the versions look quite outdated to me. have you tried the new plugin?: https://xmlbeans.apache.org/guide/Maven.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting the days trying multiple thing I found that the problem is dues to org.codehaus.mojo:xmlbeans-maven-plugin[:2.3.3].
This answer https://github.com/ethercis/openehr-java-libs/issues/1 seem to cover my case.
If you have this error:

```
error: Source option 1.4 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
error: Target option 1.4 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
```

It seem to be the plugin trying to compile code in 1.4 when it should be using a more recent jdk. This can be overiden be setting the javaSource version for xmlbeans-maven-plugin and adding the noJavac tag to prevent it from using the jdk maven is using.

```
<javaSource>1.6</javaSource><!-- only "1.5+" is actually recognized, others values revert to "1.4" code -->
<noJavac>true</noJavac><!-- prevent XmlBeans from calling javac directly with "-source 1.6", which is unsupported on new Java versions -->
```

Hope this help anyone who have the same problem.

Note: ultimatly XMLBeans should be change to a more recent version and use the new plugin provided with later version not xmlbeans-maven-plugin[:2.3.3]. In our case we needed this lib to be move to newer jenkin server not updated.

Comment: New version documented at https://xmlbeans.apache.org/guide/Maven.html

Answer (score 0):

The version of xmlbeans-maven-plugin is too old. It can be made to work with java 8 by overriding it's configuration but not with a higher java version. Try to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: New version documented at https://xmlbeans.apache.org/guide/Maven.html